# moving the contents of one file to another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 folders which contain pdb files. The names of files are same in these two folders. I would like to move the contents of files in folder1 to the corresponding files in folder 2.

```
1T15.pdb file in folder1   

ATOM     15  OD1 ASP A 197      20.828  -9.158  15.428  1.00 57.11           O
ATOM     16  OD2 ASP A 197      20.170 -11.065  14.548  1.00 56.80           O
ATOM     17  N   GLU A 198      25.562  -8.839  13.516  1.00 51.61           N 

1T15.pdb file in folder2

ATOM     54  CZ  ARG A 201      34.442 -11.903  22.369  1.00 35.51           C
ATOM     55  NH1 ARG A 201      33.939 -12.599  23.386  1.00 34.12           N               
ATOM     57  N   ALA A 202      35.516 -11.657  16.626  1.00 40.91           N 
ATOM     58  CA  ALA A 202      36.455 -11.766  15.529  1.00 49.63           C
```

Desired output

```
 ATOM     54  CZ  ARG A 201      34.442 -11.903  22.369  1.00 35.51           C 
 ATOM     55  NH1 ARG A 201      33.939 -12.599  23.386  1.00 34.12           N
 ATOM     57  N   ALA A 202      35.516 -11.657  16.626  1.00 40.91           N
 ATOM     58  CA  ALA A 202      36.455 -11.766  15.529  1.00 49.63           C
 ATOM     15  OD1 ASP A 197      20.828  -9.158  15.428  1.00 57.11           O
 ATOM     16  OD2 ASP A 197      20.170 -11.065  14.548  1.00 56.80           O
 ATOM     17  N   GLU A 198      25.562  -8.839  13.516  1.00 51.61           N
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach would be to use `basename`:

```
for i in folder1/*.pdb; do cat "$i" >> folder2/"$(basename $i)"; done
```

`>>` will create the file if not present, otherwise appends to it.